# Is adding comments/hints to a interface on a styled component possible and if so, how?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have an interface on my styled component which contains the type hints for each attribute. As shown below:

```
interface PBProps {
    color: Colours;
    bgColor: Colours;
    /** for example: 10px or 10% */
    height: string; 
    paddingLR: string;
    fontSize: string;
    width: string;
    margin: string;
    fontWeight: string;
}
```

The idea is so when you hover over height on the actual element. I have a the comment show.

so it shows "for example: 10px or 10%" in the same box that has `(JSX attribute) height: string`

[image: Image Example]

I understand you can do:

```
/**
 * @param {string} height // comment
 */
```

but this does not give the effect i wish to achieve. Is this even possible. 2 days searching has gone far enough! my google FU is not strong enough!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but just in case anyone else runs into this here's what I found...

I think the short-answer to your question is "no". The `styled-components` documentation does mention [syntax highlighting](https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#syntax-highlighting) but there's no recommendation for how one documents a styled component as far as I can tell. With syntax highlighting, you can see that inline comments (`// ...` or `/* ... */`) are supported but it doesn't look like any editor/extension parses them into the per-prop hints you're hoping for.

The normal JSDoc / TSDoc syntax (above the styled component) you mentioned at least (in VS Code) gets some documentation to be shown when hovering over the component itself but not over each prop. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70843905/how-to-use-jsdoc-to-document-styled-components-props) claims to do it but I couldn't get that working in VS Code. You may want to reach out to the JSDoc and TSDoc communities or check out packages like [this one](https://github.com/noahbuscher/react-tsdoc) that do react-specific documentation.