# How to use JSDoc to document styled components props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, styled-components, jsdoc

I have tried to document props on vscode with JSDoc multiple times on my custom styled component, but I just can't make it show up in any way.

[image: what shows up for me]

I have tried with the following syntax:

```
/**
 * @param {boolean} testprop - 20px
 */
export const Text``

export interface TextProps {
  /* 20px */ t2?: boolean
}
export const Text<TextProps>``
```

None of those 2 works so far.

- Is there any way to make it show up when you hover the prop?
- What's best practice for this?

Comment: Should the documentation go *with* the component that it describes? I.E. the second `Text` component with a `t2` prop?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I want it when you hover `t2` on `<Text t2`. I solved this problem with the second syntax (on the interface) but with `/**` instead of `/*`

Comment: I was referring to the fact that you've documented the `export const Text\`\`` component but not the `export const Text<TextProps>\`\`` component. But I think I see what you're getting at now. You wanted to jsdoc the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax worked for me:

```
export interface TextProps {
  /** 20px */ t2?: boolean
}
export const Text<TextProps>``
```

Note that the comment starts with 2 asterisks (`/**`)

Now I can hover `t2` and get the comment I set before.

[image]
[image]